# Multiple worksheets autofill error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, autofill

I want to create a button that does autofills in multiple worksheets. But it seems I could only do autofill one sheet at a time... Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)).AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 1))
Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)).AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 1))
End Sub
```

Simple at that. If I break it down into two different buttons, they work just fine. I've tried **Worksheets().Activate**, but it doesn't help. (most people don't recommend activate anyways)  Also tried writing **Sub** but the same problem persist as "error 1004".

Comment: This is just a very trivial example. To be more specific, suppose the cell(1,1) has value 9, then autofilling onto Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 1) should make the cell(2,1) has the same value as cell(1,1) which is 9. The problem doesn't occur when executing the first line, but on the second.

Comment: If your Activesheet is Sheet2 when executing the code, your first line will cause the problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've ran into a common coding error where the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) inside the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) do not have their parent explicitly defined.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1)).AutoFill _
          Destination:=.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 1))
    End With
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1)).AutoFill _
            Destination:=.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 1))
    End With
End Sub
```

Note `.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1))` and not `.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1))`. Your original was trying to define a range containing the cells on another worksheet.

The [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) can make the assignment of the parent worksheet a lot easier and doesn't obfuscate what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I added Activate:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate  'added
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)).AutoFill _
        Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 1))

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate  'added
Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)).AutoFill _
    Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 1))
```

Comment: See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Comment: I have tried this method. It probably works on other excel version. But mine (2013) shows error 1004 somehow. It seems the vba community really want to avoid using **.Activate**. And Jeeped's answer solves the problem nicely.